# Cosine similarity concept for matrices

Tags: matrix, neural-network, cosine-similarity

Can you explain to me the concept of cosine similarity for matrices? Cosine similarity for two vectors has a cos(a) concept that a is the angel of between two vectors. but for two matrices, what is the meaning of it?
Thank you so much.